How to play Four Swords on Nintendo Switch Online?
I have a Nintendo Online Subscription and would like to play Four Swords after getting the Expansion Pass, however I only have one Switch and I heard that you need 2 people to play Four Swords like the original version. I was hoping that when it eventually comes to NSO that it would only need one Switch. How do I play with a single system with my family?

I only found one source on Game FAQs saying its online only. Local connections are not possible - at least in the sense that if you only have one console (obviously having two consoles on the same network would work).
You are correct in that you will need at least two players to play the game.  The version that has been ported to Nintendo Switch Online is the original Gameboy version, which also required two or more players (not the anniversary edition that had a singleplayer option).

My take: it sounds like Nintendo either intentionally or unintentionally wanted to recreate the original experience of playing Four Sword on Gameboy, where each player would need their own Gameboy, game, and be connected via that special cable.  The only difference now is the cable is removed and replaced with an online service.

Well where can I submit ideas for Nintendo cus I've got a bunch including adding splitscreen play for this cus I really want to play it
